# What is better way to create Client record after User is registered (corresponding client record)

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Basically i have user registering himself to the app , by using devise gem.
Instead of having standard sign up form like (email, password)  i have an extra 2 fields (name, contact_nr) in total used **(name, contact_nr, email, password, password_confirm)** fields, **:name and :contact_nr attributes** exists in 'clients' table only.

```
Table name: clients

    id         :integer          not null, primary key,
    name       :string(255)
    surname    :string(255)
    contact_nr :string(255)
    user_id    :integer

  class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
  end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :client, dependent: :destroy
  after_create :update_user_client

  def name
   return unless client
   client.name
  end

  def contact_nr
    return unless client
    client.contact_nr
  end

  def update_user_client
    Client.last.update_attributes(user: self)
  end

end
```

In my RegistrationsController I have only one method

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   before_action :create_client

   private

   def create_client
     return if params[:user].blank?
    Client
       .new(name: params[:user][:name],
        contact_nr: params[:user][:contact_nr])
       .save(validate: false)
   end
 end
```

What bothers me is that kind of writing code, it feels like code smell.
How would you implement it?
Thanks guys looking forward to your answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First advice I can give is **do not separate client and user into two tables** if you don't have valid reasons and/or requirements for now. That would make things much easier.

If you have valid reasons, here are my advices on how to improve your existing state of this code piece:

- Rails and all mature gems around it rely on 'convention over configuration', so you should check if there are conventional ways to achieve same results.
- In your RegistrationsController instead of doing `params[:user].blank?` check, you should use Devise's way of doing this, provided with inherited methods as `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit` within a before_action callback.
- Instead of creating client in your controller, move that to model logic, and in your user model put `accepts_nested_attributes_for :client`.
- Since both of your models(client and user) share same name, put a `before_save` callback, so that you can pass user's name attribute to client itself.
- `after_create` callback is very risky, since it is not an atomic save (no guarantee that client will be updated after user record is updated.). So don't use it. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` will handle both create and update calls.
- If name attribute for user would be fetched through client only, there is no need to keep name within user.
- If you want to access client's `contact_nr` and `name` attributes directly from user model, then use `delegate` method inside it.

Putting all together, I would refactor that code piece as this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :client, dependent: :destroy
  accept_nested_attributes_for :client

  delegate :name,       to: :client
  delegate :contact_nr, to: :client

  # optional. if you want to keep name attr in both models.
  before_save :sync_names

  private

  def sync_names
   self.client.name = name if client.present?
  end
end

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, client_attributes: [:contact_nr]]

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end
end
```

Don't forget to update your signup and account update forms to accept nested attributes for client resource.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you are validating the data with JS and filtering with  *params.require(:client).permit*, the code looks fine. Try to create many differente scenarios in your Rspec. The test usually reveals unexpected flaws.